# how do i simulate signed 32bit integer in lua

Tags: lua, bitwise-operators

In Java, when I do following left shift operation, I get a negative result due to integer / long overflow:
0xAAAAAAAA << 7 gives me -183251938048

But, In Lua since everything is a Lua number which is 52 bit float; I am not able to trigger overflow upon left shift:
bit_lshift(0xAAAAAAAA,7) gives me 1431655680

How do I simulate 32bit signed integer in Lua??

Answer (score 1):

You write some C functions that handle this and then export them to Lua.

Though generally, Lua code shouldn't be touching things this low-level.

Comment: I am working in an Lua env. with limited control as in I cannot use external C libraries. I am looking for a pure Lua implementation.

Comment: @rohit: Then you'll have to write it yourself. In general, pure-Lua implementations of low-level concepts like this don't exist.

Comment: Though of course, if you _do_ write it, share it; then there will be a pure Lua implementation... :]  (and a pure-Lua workalike bit32 library would be kinda useful for such situations)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for bit manipulating libraries in Lua. One such library is [`bitop`](http://bitop.luajit.org/) from the author of LuaJIT, which directly contains it without the need for installation. You can also install it in standard Lua.

Another library is the [`bit32`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.7) library, which is contained in Lua 5.2.

Both libraries let you manipulate 32-bit numbers. For example with `bitop`:

```
local bit = require 'bit
print(bit.lshift(0xAAAAAAAA, 7)) --> 1431655680
```

I do not know how you got the negative number, since 1431655680 is what I get by doing (0xAAAAAAAA<<7)&0xFFFFFFFF in C (and also doing that in a "programming calculator").

Comment: Your shift operation gives you a positive number because you're dealing with unsigned integers. He specifically wants certain behavior for *signed* integers. Why, I have no idea; generally, people try to avoid bitshifts on signed integers.

Comment: That is strange, because the [bitop semantics page](http://bitop.luajit.org/semantics.html) specifically states that **" all operations are based on 32 bit integers"** and **"All bit operations are defined to return results in the range of signed 32 bit numbers"**

Comment: It might also be because he's comparing it to Java, which may have funky, non-C rules about how shifting signed integers works.

Comment: I guess the (indeed weird) Java result came about because it (1) interpreted the input `0xaaaaaaaa` as a signed 32-bit integer, _but_ (2) did the actual shifting on a 64-bit sign-extended version of the input... :

Comment: One confusing thing is that the different Lua bit libraries use different conventions... older Lua bit libs seem to sign-extend the results when converting back into numbers, but `bit32` makes everything unsigned (which seems a bit more sensible to me).

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not seen as trolling for saying this, but the best way to simulate Java from Lua would be to use Java from Lua.

If you need to emulate Java, chances are that your Lua is already embedded in it. Just expose Java's binary operations to the Lua program, so it can use them.